# OpenCV OpenNI calibrate kinect

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni, camera-calibration, calibration

I use home to capture by kinect:

```
capture.retrieve( depthMap, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP )
capture.retrieve( bgrImage, CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE )
```

Now I don't know if I have to calibrate kinect to have depth pixel value correct.
That is, if I take a pixel (u, v) from the image RBG, get the correct value of depth taking the pixels (u, v) from the image depth?

```
depthMap.at<uchar>(u,v)
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if registration is on like so:

```
cout << "REGISTRATION     " << capture.get( CV_CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION ) << endl;
```

and if it's not, set it like so:

```
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION,1);
```

or:

```
if(capture.get( CV_CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION ) == 0) capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION,1);
```